# How do I detect when three.js throws an error during rendering?

Tags: error-handling, three.js

When doing some stuff with `three.js` I have noticed some limitations depending on what client the code is run on. One example is that if I have a lot of `MeshPhongMaterial`s and `Light`s, and try it out on a low-end laptop/phone, I would get shader errors. Sometimes the `requestAnimationFrame()` would stop executing completely and sometimes I would just get walls and walls with this error (and WebGL warnings).

My question is if it is possible to catch these errors? Made a little stress-test script using `try-catch` but the `catch` is never called even after the errors and warnings.

```
var rendering = function()
{
    lights.push(new THREE.PointLight());
    lights[lights.length-1].position.set((Math.random()*10)-5,(Math.random()*10)-5,(Math.random()*10)-5);
    scene.add(lights[lights.length-1]);
    try
    {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("Limit!"); // never shown
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(rendering);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.error = yourFunction()
console.warning = yourFunction()

Examine the messages in there, and do something with them..

Comment: Thanks. That took care of the red blocks of error, but it did not take care of the yellow blocks with WebGL warnings. Then again, the red blocks traced back to my running script while the yellow blocks stayed within three.js, so maybe nothing one can do about it. At least I can stop the production of lights and take a step back to recover.

Comment: You can also override console.warn the same way as I described above.

I wouldn't generally recommend this, as its better to fix warnings/errors if possible, but I'm just posting this because sometimes you just have to do something horrible in order to ship, or track something down, or log something bad.